# A Database Management System that understands Relational Algebra Queries

Tags: database, educational

I am a Computer Science student and we are currently learning [Relational Algebra](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/dbms/relational_algebra.htm). I wish to be able to write Relational Algebra Queries and test to see what they return. Thus, I am looking for a Database Management System that can understand Relational Algebra Queries.

My Criteria are:

- Should be for all intents and purposes a Database Management System. That is:

  - I should be able to create tables.
  - I should be able to insert data into tables.
  - I should be able to query tables, and have it output the result of the query.
  - Although I don't really care about the exact implementation of it.
- Must accept Relational Algebra Queries. Again, I don't care about the implementation. It could translate it to SQL and then query an SQL Database if it wants, as long as it can understand the queries I give it.

This is for educational purposes.

Comment: I am not very familiar with the whole database ecosystem and functionalities. Aren't [MySQL](https://www.mysql.com/) queries relational [algebra queries or are they set operations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html)? You probably did take a look at that already, right?

Comment: Command line application or REPL is OK?

Comment: But how do you want to express your relational algebra? Strings? Graphs?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [des.sourceforge.net](http://des.sourceforge.net).

There you will find DES, which includes a relational algebra interpreter for your RA queries and allows you to define relations and insert data with SQL DDL statements.